# Need help in configuring LDAP acl

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, acl, openldap, access-control

I am trying to configure acl in such a way users with attribute allowedService with application name can only login to that particular application.

We have users as follows:

```
dn: ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com

dn: uid=user1,ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
uid: user1
allowedService: gitlab

dn: uid=user2,ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
uid: user2
allowedService: zabbix

dn: uid=user3,ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
objectClass: top
uid: user3
allowedService: zabbix
```

We created an user as follows:

```
dn: cn=gitlab,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
cn: gitlab
uid: gitlab
```

Now in application we given the details as follows:
gitlab configuration

```
base: ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
uid: uid
bind_dn: cn=gitlab,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com
password: password
```

Now in acl we tried various options as follows:

```
root@geopc:/# ldapsearch -Q -LLL -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config '(olcDatabase={1}hdb)' olcAccess
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to dn.subtree="ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" by self write by * write
olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" by self write by * auth
olcAccess: {4}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" filter="(allowedService=gitlab)" by dn.exact="cn=gitlab,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" write by self write
```

But with this no user can able to login. But we change `olcAccess: {3}to dn.subtree="ou=People,dc=prime,dc=ds,dc=geo,dc=com" by self write by * write` , all users can login.

But actually we need is only the user1 need only to login to gitlab application. And the users user2 and user3 need only to login to zabbix application

Can anyone please help me to configure acl for this. Thanks in advance.

Thanks

Geo

Answer (score 0):

This is not what ACLs are for. They don't control who can login. They control what parts of the subtree a logged-in user can read or modify.